# apache mq - aggregator not receiving updated body from processor on target queues

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm at a loss on this guys - can't figure out why my aggregator isn't receiving my updated message body from the processor on the target queues that I'm aggregating responses from. In the processors of the targeted queues, the body is updated and I can print to console the updated body without issue. Though, when I try to print to console the message body from the aggregator, the message doesn't have the updates that were made in the processor(s).

Here's my route:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){

        public void configure(){

            from("jms:queue:ready_for_test")
            .multicast(new CompAggregationStrategy())
                .parallelProcessing()
                .to("jms:queue:test1", "jms:queue:test2", "jms:queue:test3")
            .end()
            .to("jms:queue:highest_value");

            from("jms:queue:test1").process(new InstProcessor("Comp1"));
            from("jms:queue:test2").process(new InstProcessor("Comp2"));
            from("jms:queue:test3").process(new InstProcessor("Comp3"));

        }
```

Here is InstProcessor:

```
    public class InsuranceProcessor implements Processor{

    private String providerName;

    public InsuranceProcessor(String name) {
        this.providerName = name;
    }

    public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception {


        double rate = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        String body = e.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String[] msgArray = body.split("|");

        //do a bunch of stuff, removed for brevity
        //this stuff calculates rate

        //build out new exchange body
        StringBuilder newExchange = new StringBuilder();
        newExchange.append(body);
        newExchange.append("|");
        newExchange.append((int)rate);

        //replace old exchange body with new exchange body
        e.getIn().setBody(newExchange.toString());

        //System.out.println(newExchange.toString()); //this displays correctly

    }

}
```

And my Aggregator:

```
    public class CompAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy{
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange){

        //should always be true on first response
        if(oldExchange == null){
            return newExchange;
        }

//both of these lines outputting to console output my original message, without the rate appended to the msg
        //System.out.println(newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        //System.out.println(oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));

        Double oldQuote = Double.parseDouble(oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).split("|")[11]);
        Double newQuote = Double.parseDouble(newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).split("|")[11]);

        if (oldQuote.doubleValue() <= newQuote.doubleValue()) {
            return oldExchange;
        } else {
            return newExchange;
        }

    }

}
```

I for the life of me cannot figure this out. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. What are the "targeted queues" to talk about in the description?

Comment: The targeted queues are the multiple test queues that I'm sending messages to in order to be processed with multicast(new CompAggregationStrategy())
                .parallelProcessing()
                .to("jms:queue:test1", "jms:queue:test2", "jms:queue:test3")

Comment: I see. I don't use the InOut exchange pattern often, but have you set up the exchange pattern as InOut, eg jms:MyQueue?exchangePattern=InOut. See http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html